# PHP. ¿Cómo introducir variable (sintaxis) dentro de json?

Tags: php, json

Estoy tratando de enviar mensajes de Whatsapp via api, atraves de waapi.app. pero me da error al introducir variables dentro de array json.
Este es el ejemplo.

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('POST', 
'https://waapi.app/api/v1/instances/5116/client/action/send- 
media', [
'body' => '{
"chatId":"123456789@c.us",
"mediaUrl":"https://waapi.app/android-chrome-192x192.png",
"mediaCaption":"Texto de Imagen"
   }',
   'headers' => [
   'accept' => 'application/json',
   'content-type' => 'application/json',
   ],
 ]);
```

El codigo de arriba funciona correctamente.

Lo que pretendo hacer es esto:

```
$ChatId = "123456789@c.us";
$Url = "https://waapi.app/android-chrome-192x192.png";
$Caption =  "Texto de Imagen";
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('POST', 
'https://waapi.app/api/v1/instances/5116/client/action/send- 
media', [
'body' => '{
"chatId":$ChatId,
"mediaUrl":$Url,
"mediaCaption":$Caption
   }',
   'headers' => [
   'accept' => 'application/json',
   'content-type' => 'application/json',
   ],
 ]);
```

Pero siempre me da error. Donde estan las variable intente:

`"chatId":"\""$ChatId"\""`, (este con echo funciona bien, pero dentro del array no)
`"chatId='"'$ChatId'"'` (no funciono)
`"chatId"= {$ChatId}` (tampoco funciona)
`"chatId"= "{$ChatId}"`(error)
Por favor, si alguien sabe, les agradeceria mucho.

Luis

Comment: esta mal por que haces esto '$variable' las comillas simples no exapanden variables, debes usar las dobles => "

Comment: otra forma es concatenar ' texto: '.$variable

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. El tema es que si pongo comillas doble me da error syntax error, unexpected double-quote mark, expecting "]"... . Quiero colocar la variable y que el resultado sea 'contenido variable' dentro de comillas simple.

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende y es confusa en varios puntos. Tampoco se ve el código problemático en su contexto. Si que quieres crear un JSON no puedes usar comillas simples al estilo: `'key': 'value'`, porque eso no validará, debe ser `"key": "value"`. En cuanto a crearlo desde código PHP, hay mil formas. La mejor es crear un array o un objeto y luego generar el JSON a partir de él. Si se trata de concatenación directa, puedes rodear esa cadena de comillas dobles y escapar con ``\`` las comillas dobles dentro de los valores, y/o usar `sprintf()`. De todos modos, no queda claro el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano, por contestar. Reformule la pregunta

Comment: Sigue sin entenderse. Explica con claridad  qué estructura debe tener lo que intentas mandar en tu variable `$response`. Eso es lo más importante para poder ayudarte. Es confuso lo que quieres crear dentro de los corchetes `[ ]`, luego de la URL. Si pones un ejemplo de cómo debería quedar `$response` correctamente sería lo mejor.

Comment: @A.Cedano, la verdad no se bien lo de la extructura, tome un ejemplo de la documentacion de waapi: https://waapi.readme.io/reference/post_instances-id-client-action-send-media

Comment: en el body va un json. lo podes armar a mano com un string (poniendo las llaves y comillas y tal ). o pones las cosas en un array/objeto y lo [jsnoendoeas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: `'body' => json_encode([ "chatId" => $ChatId, "mediaUrl"=>$Url, "mediaCaption" => $Caption]),`

Comment: Te sugiero que hagas algo así: `$data=array(
    'body'=>json_encode(array('chatId'=>$ChatId,'mediaUrl'=>$Url,'mediaCaption'=>$Caption)),
    'headers'=>array('accept'=>'application/json','content-type' => 'application/json')
);` y luego: `$response = $client->request('POST', 
'https://waapi.app/api/v1/instances/5116/client/action/send-media',$data);` Lo que hemos hecho ha sido meter en `$data` todo lo que vas a enviar, trabajando así de forma más ordenada. También es conveniente en estos casos usar `json_encode()`, porque convertirá a un formato legible casos como palabras acentuadas.

Comment: Por cierto, este valor: `https://waapi.app/api/v1/instances/5116/client/action/send-media` está mal en el código de la pregunta, hay saltos de línea, luego del guión de la palabra `send-` lo cual puede que produzca una URL inválida en el contexto real del programa.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por responder. Gracias, no estoy en mi PC ahora, cuando regrese haré las modificaciones que me sugeriste y te contesto. Abrazo.

Comment: y el mensaje de error que te da cual es?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu ejemplo

```
'{
  "chatId":$ChatId,
  "mediaUrl":$Url,
  "mediaCaption":$Caption
 }'
```

Dejando de lado el tema formato para armar strings que es lo que te genera errores, armandolo de esa forma no te garantiza un json válido.

Si el api requiere un json, lo mas conveniente es hacer que php genere un json válido. Para eso podes crear un array u objeto con las cosas a mandar y que php lo transforme a json usando [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) .

Algo así:

```
$ChatId = "123456789@c.us";
$Url = "https://waapi.app/android-chrome-192x192.png";
$Caption =  "Texto de Imagen";

$body_json = json_encode([
  "chatId" => $ChatId,
  "mediaUrl" => $Url,
  "mediaCaption" => $Caption
]);

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request(
  'POST',
  'https://waapi.app/api/v1/instances/5116/client/action/send-media',
  [
    'body' => $body_json,
    'headers' => [
      'accept' => 'application/json',
      'content-type' => 'application/json',
    ],
  ]
);
```

Comment: Por favor, disculpen la demora por responderle. Finalmente la recomendación @alo Malbarez fue mi solución. Funciona perfectamente asi. Muchas gracias alo. Gracias a todos por responder. Abrazo fuerte.